# How to store ActiveCell addresses into dynamic VBA array in Excel?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am using cells as "buttons" by hyperlinking them to VBA function:

`=HYPERLINK("#vba_function()", "jump_text")`

When "button" is clicked, I want cell address to be saved to some array `clicked_cells` so it can not be clicked again. Pseudocode:

`if ActiveCell.Address in clicked_cells then MsgBox("That cell already selected. Choose another.")`

How do I initialize such an array and how do I update it within `vba_function`?

Comment: You can use a scripting dictionary to collect the addresses, either as a global variable, or a Static inside your function.

Comment: Can you give me a code example? Keep getting 'Reference isn't valid'. Trying 
```Public clicked_cells as Scripting.Dictionary
   Set clicked_cells = New Scripting.Dictionary
   With clicked_cells
        .Add "key", "val"
   End With```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public clicked_cells As Scripting.Dictionary

Function vba_function()
    Dim addr
    If clicked_cells Is Nothing Then
        Set clicked_cells = New Scripting.Dictionary
    End If

    addr = Selection.Address

    If clicked_cells.Exists(addr) Then
        MsgBox "Already clicked that " & (Timer - clicked_cells(addr)) & " seconds ago"
    Else
        clicked_cells.Add addr, Timer
    End If
    Set vba_function = Selection
End Function
```